# Error "Stack around variable was corrupted"

Tags: c, c99

Error "Stack arround variable BITS was corrupted", MSVS 2013, C99.
Why it doesn't works?
If I allocate

```
NAME[(LENGTH) / CHAR_BIT + 1]
```

the programm would be working normally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define CREATE_BIT_FIELD(NAME, LENGTH) \
    unsigned char NAME[(LENGTH) / CHAR_BIT + ((LENGTH) % CHAR_BIT) ? 1 : 0]

#define SET_BIT(NAME, N) \
    NAME[(N) / CHAR_BIT] |= ((unsigned char)1 << ((N) % CHAR_BIT))

#define CLEAR_BIT(NAME, N) \
    NAME[(N) / CHAR_BIT] &= (UCHAR_MAX - ((unsigned char)1 << ((N) % CHAR_BIT)))

#define IS_SETTED(NAME, N) \
    (NAME[(N) / CHAR_BIT] & ((unsigned char)1 << ((N) % CHAR_BIT)))

int main(void)
{ 
    CREATE_BIT_FIELD(BITS, 16);

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        SET_BIT(BITS, i);

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        putchar(IS_SETTED(BITS, i) ? '1' : '0');

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The conventional way to round up in this context would be `unsigned char NAME[(LENGTH + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT]`, avoiding the conditional. Since the size is computed at compile time, it isn't an efficiency issue; it is just a simpler expression, and people will recognize it more readily.

Comment: It's genious and cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
unsigned char NAME[(LENGTH) / CHAR_BIT + ((LENGTH) % CHAR_BIT) ? 1 : 0]
```

is being evaluated always to `1` add parentheses

```
unsigned char NAME[(LENGTH) / CHAR_BIT + (((LENGTH) % CHAR_BIT) ? 1 : 0)]
                                      /* ^ here                        ^ and here */
```

otherwise it's evaluated as

```
((LENGTH) / CHAR_BIT + (((LENGTH) % CHAR_BIT)) ? 1 : 0
```

it's because of operator precedence.